# Julia fails to precompile packages Plots

Tags: julia, precompile

After I excute Pkg.precompile(), the REPL return the information like following:

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.precompile()
Precompiling project...

  ✗ GR

  ✗ Plots

  0 dependencies successfully precompiled in 40 seconds (130 already precompiled)

ERROR: The following 1 direct dependency failed to precompile:

Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80]

Failed to precompile Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80] to C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\compiled\v1.6\Plots\jl_DB20.tmp.
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: not a path: \`C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\GR\xhzFJ\deps\deps.jl\`

ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: not a path: `C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\GR\xhzFJ\deps\deps.jl`
Stacktrace:
 [1] RelocatableFolders.Path(mod::Module, dir::String, path::String)
   @ RelocatableFolders C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\RelocatableFolders\PYUl8\src\RelocatableFolders.jl:51
 [2] top-level scope
   @ C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\GR\xhzFJ\src\GR.jl:36
 [3] include
   @ .\Base.jl:384 [inlined]
 [4] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::String)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:1235
 [5] top-level scope
   @ none:1
 [6] eval
   @ .\boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [7] eval(x::Expr)
   @ Base.MainInclude .\client.jl:446
 [8] top-level scope
   @ none:1
in expression starting at C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\GR\xhzFJ\src\GR.jl:2
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: Failed to precompile GR [28b8d3ca-fb5f-59d9-8090-bfdbd6d07a71] to C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\compiled\v1.6\GR\jl_B11E.tmp.
Stacktrace:
  [1] error(s::String)
    @ Base .\error.jl:33
  [2] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String, internal_stderr::IOContext{Base.PipeEndpoint}, internal_stdout::IOContext{IOStream}, ignore_loaded_modules::Bool)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1385
  [3] compilecache(pkg::Base.PkgId, path::String)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1329
  [4] _require(pkg::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1043
  [5] require(uuidkey::Base.PkgId)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:936
  [6] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:923
  [7] include(mod::Module, _path::String)
    @ Base .\Base.jl:384
  [8] include(x::String)
    @ Plots C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\E2187\src\Plots.jl:1
  [9] top-level scope
    @ C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\E2187\src\Plots.jl:227
 [10] include
    @ .\Base.jl:384 [inlined]
 [11] include_package_for_output(pkg::Base.PkgId, input::String, depot_path::Vector{String}, dl_load_path::Vector{String}, load_path::Vector{String}, concrete_deps::Vector{Pair{Base.PkgId, UInt64}}, source::Nothing)
    @ Base .\loading.jl:1235
 [12] top-level scope
    @ none:1
 [13] eval
    @ .\boot.jl:360 [inlined]
 [14] eval(x::Expr)
    @ Base.MainInclude .\client.jl:446
 [15] top-level scope
    @ none:1
in expression starting at C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\E2187\src\backends\gr.jl:6
in expression starting at C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\packages\Plots\E2187\src\Plots.jl:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(msg::String)
   @ Pkg.Types C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\Types.jl:55
 [2] precompile(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context; internal_call::Bool, strict::Bool, warn_loaded::Bool, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
   @ Pkg.API C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\API.jl:1265
 [3] precompile
   @ C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\API.jl:921 [inlined]
 [4] #precompile#196
   @ C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\API.jl:919 [inlined]
 [5] precompile()
   @ Pkg.API C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\Pkg\src\API.jl:919
 [6] top-level scope
   @ REPL[2]:1
```

Please help me!

More details:

- Microsoft Windows [10.0.17763.2803]
- Julia Version 1.6.6 (2022-03-28). Julia is installed by the installer downloaded from https://julialang.org/downloads/

I am a postgraduate majoring in physics. I am interested in computing and programming. From my classmates the julia lang is a programming language facing futrue because of its advanced programming philosophy. However, what I did not expect is that I meet the problem I can not resolve so soon. (This paragraph is for the prompt "Most is code, please add more details")

Comment: Please add some more details to the question: Are you running this directly under Windows, or is it on WSL, or some other way? Which version of Julia,  and is it from the Windows Store or downloaded some other way? It seems you're running this as the Administrator user, are you able to install the packages if you are a normal user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not even know what have happened till now. However I find the solution for my question and I have succeed in resolving it. Having excute `Pkg.add("Plots")`, just excute the following codes:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("GR")
Pkg.build("GR")
Pkg.precompile()
```

The answer is from [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/error-plots-package-installation-with-1-7-1-release-of-julia/75308/4)